# Detect space that shows as a space but encoding wise is something else

Tags: php, encoding, character-encoding, tinymce

I'm using TinyMCE editor

And I'm trying to remove all extra spaces in the text, if any, before the text is saved into database

```
preg_replace('/\s+/', ' ', $text) or any other variation, simply changes nothing
```

In my database I can see all the extra spaces in the text

So I'm wondering, if the spaces are encoded somehow (different than regular), and I just don't target them right..

How can I see how they are really encoded?

```
&nbsp; / U+0020 / U+00A0 / other?
```

(I use utf-8 all over)

Comment: The text is just some random words and some long spaces.. it works when I try inside php. But not with text generated/saved in tinyMCE.. Even though it looks IDENTICAL. I suspect it is not just outputting regular spaces. But how do I test or find whats really inside those spaces?

Comment: *Show* to us so we can analyze.